# How to handle assertion errors in third party Node.js libraries

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest

I'm using the Node.js request module request like so

```
let request = require('request');
request(SOME_URL, { proxy }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + error);
        return;
    }
    // my actual code here that usually runs
});
```

98% of the time this works, but sometimes I use a proxy that acts up, which causes some weird behavior. My code will be humming along fine until it comes to an abrupt halt with the following stack trace:

```
assert.js:85
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
  ^

AssertionError: 542 == 0
    at ClientRequest.onConnect (/home/stephen/apps/my-cool-app/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:159:14)
    at ClientRequest.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitThree (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:194:7)
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:395:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:548:20)
```

Now, I would kind have expected any errors to be returned in the callback. But that's not happening, so I can't handle it appropriately there.

I tried surrounding this in a try/catch block, like the following:

```
try {
    request(SOME_URL, { proxy }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + error);
            return;
        }
        // my actual code here that usually runs
    });
} catch (err) {
     console.log('Caught error: ' + err);
}
```

But this also doesn't work -- I still get the AssertionError and my program stops.

So, my question is: How do I handle this gracefully? If I encounter this `AssertionError` I want to cancel (or ignore) the request and move on with another one, not have my program come crashing to a halt.

Comment: You will probably have to edit the library to fix it or control the conditions so it never hits that assertion.  It's bad behavior to throw inside an async callback (except for promises which are wrapped in try/catch automatically) because it can't be caught by the higher level code.  You could probably work around it by redefining whatever assert function they are using inside their module and not otherwise touching the code.

Comment: I had the exact same issue as you've encountered.. I agree with jfriend00 above that the only good way to fix this issue is to actually fix the library code and handle this gracefully. I've changed the code in tunnel-agent to return an error instead of doing this assertion.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the only way to handle those unwelcome assertions:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', err => {

    if (err.name === 'AssertionError') {
        // handle the assertion here or just ignore it..

    }


});
```